# how to save the iphone audio file in document directory

Tags: iphone

I have implemented audio recording in my application but i need to know how to save the audio recording file in document directory and retrieve same file in other class for playing audio.

Here is the source code.

```
-(void)startPushed
{
        NSMutableDictionary *rs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [rs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [rs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [rs setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"]]];

        recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:rs error:&error];
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        [recorder record];


        NSArray *docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docDir = [docPath objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", recordedTmpFile]];
        NSLog(@"%@", fullPath);
}

 -(void)playbackPushed
    {
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Play Path:%@", recordedTmpFile);
        [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [avPlayer play];
    }
```

Please tell me how to read and write the audio file(.caf format) in document directory
and also give the information for audio playing in other class.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

access Document Directory in iOS with this code

```
-(NSURL *)documentDirectory{
return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```

}

and Use NSFileManager to copy file to the path.